# Why is Ansible not loading roles with dot in the name?

Tags: ansible

I have a simple play

```
---
- name: nfs.yml
  hosts: nfs
  become: yes

  roles:
    - { role: common,             tags: ["common"] }
    - { role: geerlingguy.nfs,    tags: ["nfs"] }
```

This has always worked for me. Now I am trying to help a user for whom this doesn't work.

To get it to work the user has to rename the role to remove the dot for example to

```
---
- name: nfs.yml
  hosts: nfs
  become: yes

  roles:
    - { role: common,             tags: ["common"] }
    - { role: geerlingguy_nfs,    tags: ["nfs"] }
```

Ansible seems to skip those type of role without error. What is the rationale for this behavior? How can it be configured? This seems to be a undocumented feature.

Comment: The value of role_name will be converted to lowercase, and ‘-‘ and ‘.’ will be translated to ‘_’.

Answer (score 0):

As per ansible link https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/creating_role.html

The charaters - and . will be converted to "_"

[image: as per ansible role name]